# Java JInternalFrame to JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jinternalframe

I have got a JFrame A und 2 JInternalFrame B und C. I want to show these two Frames B and C in a JPanel, rather than a JInternalFrame. Then i will put the jpanel to another Frame. So B and C both will be shown as own JFrame.
So my question is:
How can i move JInternalFrame components to JPanel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be quite simple since both `JInternalFrame` and `JPanel` are subclasses of `JComponent`.

You could rename the `extends JInternalFrame`to `extends JPanel` at the beginning of your frame, change the constructor (since IIRC the ones of `JInternalFrame` require title, resizable and so on) and check if there are compilation errors (maybe yes, but small things) then you are done..

Comment: it is as simple as you say i think.what about the actions? i must change actions,listeners too.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show these two Frames B and C in a JPanel, rather than a JInternalFrame.

Why? Internal frames are designed to be used in a desktop pane. In order to get them to display properly in a JPanel you would basically need to customize the panel to work like a desktop pane. Why reinvent the wheel.

> Then i will put the jpanel to another Frame. So B and C both will be shown as own JFrame.

So move the desktop pane to another frame. Why move them to a panel first.

Use the API the way it was designed to be used and you won't have problems.

Comment: because in my application i have dockings and i will show there internalframes which i want. Thats why i must remove internalframes from desktop pane. so i can use which i want